# xcode error: The selected run destination is not valid for this action

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

my app in 4.3 simulator and device work well. Now i want to test it in 4.0 simulator and i have also 4.2.1 device. So i set ios deployment target to 4.0 (tried also 4.2), but xcode give me that error :The selected run destination is not valid for this action.

Then i added my second iphone to provisioning profile and i see it in device in xcode for build but same thing: The selected run destination is not valid for this action.

How can i read (or if one can explain me) where to find how to setup project for run in 4.0 4.2 and 4.3 simulator for example?

I'm trying to "click everywhere" also in manage schemes but can't find nothing usefull.

Thx in advice.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set the iOS Deployment Target on both the Project and the Target items. When you click the project icon in the Project navigator, on the left side you will se two groups, Project and Targets. Project will contain your project, and the Targets section will have your app and unit test targets. Set the iOS Deployment on your project settings and in the target (app, not tests) settings.

Comment: +1 Targeting iOS 3.0 with a base SDK of iOS 4.3 gave me this problem (I had only updated the build settings in the target). Adjusting the project build settings to match resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the base SDK for the project:

1) Click on your PROJECT_NAME in the Project Navigator

2) Click on your PROJECT_NAME under the 'PROJECT' label on the next panel

3) Click on the 'Build Settings' tab

4) Under 'Architectures'->'Base SDK' -> 'Debug', select the 'Latest (iOS4.3)'

5) Under 'Code Signing'->'Debug'->'Any iOS SDK', select your Apple Provisioning Profile

6) Under your project schemes you should be able to select iPhone/iPad.

Voila!
PS: You should be able to see all the SDKs that you have installed on step 4).

Answer (score 0):

Check your SDK and sign in identity in your build configuration. That's how I solved this issue.