# Problem in the last version of XCode (4) on Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4 - The selected run destination is not valid for this action.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319251/xcode-4-the-selected-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-this-action)

Hi everyone,
I'm currently learning Obj-C and I'm dealing with a book that provides a lot of sample xcode projects.
I've a problem when trying to run the code: it appears an alert saying **"The selected run destination is not valid for this action"**.

This happen only in xcode 4+. In the old version all work fine.
Can you help me solving this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate [Xcode 4 - The selected run destination is not valid for this action.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319251/xcode-4-the-selected-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-this-action) or try [xcode error: The selected run destination is not valid for this action.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398254/xcode-error-the-selected-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-this-action)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also.

You need to make sure the Base SDK is set correctly for the debug and release of you Application Target.

If its missing i.e 10.5 then you will get this message.

in my v4 of xcode it does not have a 10.5 sdk. But my Application Target was set to 10.5.
So I needed to change it to 10.6.

I did this by selecting the Targets Build settings of the Project.
and then changing the base SDK's there.